# Magento EE Cannot upgrade from 2.2.7 to 2.3.3 via composer

Tags: upgrade, magento2.3.3

I'm trying to update Magento EE 2.2.7 to version 2.3.3 using the command line:

I have tried using bellow command but getting errors

- List item

> Command :

composer update

**Output:**

```
    Problem 1
                - magento/framework 101.0.9 requires php ~7.0.13|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
                - magento/framework 100.1.18 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
                - magento/framework 101.0.8 requires php ~7.0.13|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
                - magento/framework 100.1.17 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
                - magento/framework 101.0.7 requires php ~7.0.13|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
                - magento/framework 100.1.16 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
                - magento/framework 101.0.6 requires php ~7.0.13|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
                - magento/framework 100.1.15 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
                - magento/framework 100.1.14 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
                - magento/framework 101.0.5 requires php ~7.0.13|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
                - magento/framework 101.0.4 requires php 7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
                - magento/framework 100.1.13 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
                - magento/framework 101.0.3 requires php 7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
                - magento/framework 100.1.12 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
                - magento/framework 101.0.2 requires php 7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
                - magento/framework 100.1.11 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
                - magento/framework 100.1.10 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
                - magento/framework 101.0.1 requires php 7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
                - magento/framework 101.0.0 requires php 7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
                - magento/framework 100.1.9 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
                - magento/framework 101.0.0-rc30 requires php 7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
                - magento/framework 101.0.0-rc23 requires php 7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
                - magento/framework 101.0.0-rc22 requires php 7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
                - magento/framework 101.0.0-rc21 requires php 7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
                - magento/framework 100.1.8 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
                - magento/framework 100.1.7 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
                - magento/framework 100.1.6 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
                - magento/framework 100.1.5 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
                - magento/framework 100.1.4 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
                - magento/framework 100.1.3 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
                - magento/framework 100.1.2 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
                - magento/framework 100.1.1 requires php ~5.6.0|7.0.2|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
                - magento/framework 100.1.0 requires php ~5.6.0|7.0.2|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
                - magento/framework 100.1.0-rc3 requires php ~5.6.0|7.0.2|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
                - magento/framework 100.1.0-rc2 requires php ~5.5.22|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
                - magento/framework 100.1.0-rc1 requires php ~5.5.22|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
                - magento/framework 101.0.7 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
                - snowdog/theme-blank-sass 1.100.4 requires magento/framework 100.1.*||101.0.* -> satisfiable by magento/framework[101.0.7, 100.1.0-rc1, 100.1.0-rc2, 100.1.0-rc3, 100.1.0, 100.1.1, 100.1.2, 100.1.3, 100.1.4, 100.1.5, 100.1.6, 100.1.7, 100.1.8, 101.0.0-rc21, 101.0.0-rc22, 101.0.0-rc23, 101.0.0-rc30, 100.1.9, 101.0.0, 101.0.1, 100.1.10, 100.1.11, 101.0.2, 100.1.12, 101.0.3, 100.1.13, 101.0.4, 101.0.5, 100.1.14, 100.1.15, 101.0.6, 100.1.16, 100.1.17, 101.0.8, 100.1.18, 101.0.9, 101.0.10].
                - snowdog/theme-blank-sass 1.100.4 requires magento/framework 100.1.*||101.0.* -> satisfiable by magento/framework[101.0.7, 100.1.0-rc1, 100.1.0-rc2, 100.1.0-rc3, 100.1.0, 100.1.1, 100.1.2, 100.1.3, 100.1.4, 100.1.5, 100.1.6, 100.1.7, 100.1.8, 101.0.0-rc21, 101.0.0-rc22, 101.0.0-rc23, 101.0.0-rc30, 100.1.9, 101.0.0, 101.0.1, 100.1.10, 100.1.11, 101.0.2, 100.1.12, 101.0.3, 100.1.13, 101.0.4, 101.0.5, 100.1.14, 100.1.15, 101.0.6, 100.1.16, 100.1.17, 101.0.8, 100.1.18, 101.0.9, 101.0.10].
                - magento/framework 101.0.10 requires zendframework/zend-stdlib ^2.7.7 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-stdlib[2.7.7].
                - Can only install one of: zendframework/zend-stdlib[3.2.1, 2.7.7].
                - Can only install one of: zendframework/zend-stdlib[3.2.1, 2.7.7].
                - magento/product-enterprise-edition 2.3.3 requires zendframework/zend-stdlib ^3.2.1 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-stdlib[3.2.1].
                - Installation request for magento/product-enterprise-edition 2.3.3 -> satisfiable by magento/product-enterprise-edition[2.3.3].
                - Installation request for snowdog/theme-blank-sass 1.100.4 -> satisfiable by snowdog/theme-blank-sass[1.100.4].
```

PHP version
[image]
if anyone has an idea help me..!

Comment: check in your config server file   `unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock`; for nginx something like this for apache

Comment: @xanka for apache what I do?

Comment: check on your php.ini `LoadModule php7_module modules/libphp7.so` just sample

Comment: This is maybe PHP version issue, you should try to down PHP version to **PHP 7.0**

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2.3.1 is certified and tested on PHP 7.2.11. Magento 2.3.3 adds support for PHP 7.3.

May be php version issue. So try using **php7.2.11** or **php7.2.19** version.

Answer (score 0):

This is the Error of PHP Version, First Upgrade your PHP Version then run Upgradation Process.

```
PHP Version Compatiable with Magento 2.3.3 is -> ~7.1.3, ~7.2.0, ~7.3.0
```

[Technology stack requirements](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html)

Complete all this Technology Stack Requirements then Upgrade Magento.

```
============================================
*Upgrade PHP version Command in Cent OS*

First Remove 
-----------------------
 yum remove -y php72w
 yum remove -y php72w*
 yum remove -y php72*

Then Install 
----------------------

rpm -Uvh https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
rpm -Uvh https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el7/webtatic-release.rpm

yum -y install php73w php73w-opcache
yum -y install php73w-fpm php73w-opcache
yum -y install yum-plugin-replace
yum replace php-common --replace-with=php73w-common

yum -y install php73w php73w-bcmath php73w-cli php73w-common php73w-dba php73w-devel php73w-embedded php73w-enchant php73w-fpm php73w-gd php73w-imap php73w-interbase php73w-intl php73w-ldap php73w-mbstring php73w-mcrypt php73w-mysql php73w-opcache php73w-pdo php73w-pdo_dblib php73w-pear php73w-pecl-apcu php73w-pecl-imagick php73w-pecl-memcached php73w-pecl-mongodb php73w-pecl-redis php73w-pecl-xdebug php73w-pgsql php73w-phpdbg php73w-process php73w-pspell php73w-recode php73w-snmp php73w-soap php73w-tidy php73w-xml php73w-xmlrpc

Restart server
-------------------------
 php -v
service httpd restart
service httpd status
service php-fpm status
service php-fpm start
service php-fpm status
service nginx status
iptables -F
setenforce=0
============================================
```

Comment: all extension is installed as per ref - (https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html). my PHP version is (7.2.25)

Comment: You need to go with PHP 7.3.0 or 7.2.0

Comment: I have updated answer from this you can easily upgrade your PHP Version

Answer (score 0):

**Follow This Steps :-**

> **Step 1:-** sudo apt-get install -y php7.1 libapache2-mod-php7.1 php7.1-common php7.1-gd php7.1-mysql php7.1-curl php7.1-intl
>   php7.1-xsl php7.1-mbstring php7.1-zip php7.1-bcmath php7.1-iconv
>   php7.1-soap
>
> **Step 2 :-** composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.3.3 --no-update
>
> **Step 3 :-** composer require --dev allure-framework/allure-phpunit:~1.2.0
>   friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer:~2.13.0 lusitanian/oauth:~0.8.10
>   magento/magento-coding-standard:~1.0.0
>   magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework:~2.3.14
>   pdepend/pdepend:2.5.2 phpunit/phpunit:~6.5.0 sebastian/phpcpd:~3.0.0
>   squizlabs/php_codesniffer:3.3.1 --sort-packages --no-update
>
> **Step 4 :-** composer remove --dev sjparkinson/static-review fabpot/php-cs-fixer --no-update
>
> **Step 5 :-** Open composer.json and edit the "autoload": "psr-4" section to include "Zend\Mvc\Controller\":
>   "setup/src/Zend/Mvc/Controller/":
>
> **Step 6 :-** composer update

Answer (score 0):

you have to use upgrade script:

> https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/cli/upgrade-with-script.html

Upgrading your Magento installation with our script, which makes the upgrade process semi-automated, is the preferred method.

```
php -f pre_composer_update_2.3.php -- --root='/path/to/magento' \
--repo='https://repo.magento.com/' \
--edition='enterprise' \
--version='2.3.3'
```